# configuring content-security-policy for apache virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, virtualhost, content-security-policy

I have Apache 2.4 with these sites configured in the httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:8080 *:8084>
    DocumentRoot "c:\apache_php\sites\public"
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80 *:8080 *:8081>
    DocumentRoot "c:\apache_php\sites\shared"
    ServerName shared.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The shared.mydomain.com domain has a javascript file that I want to load in the [www.mydomain.com/index.php](http://www.mydomain.com/index.php) with:

```
<script src="http://shared.mydomain.com:8081/js/file.js"></script>
```

I created an .htaccess file in the root of both the /public and /shared folders that contains this:

```
Header unset Content-Security-Policy
Header add Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' *.mydomain.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"
```

and I enabled mod_headers in the httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

I restarted Apache after adding the .htaccess files.

However, I keep getting:

```
Refused to load the script 'http://shared.mydomain.com:8081/js/file.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'none'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-Ar45cH3tWULAEHfrKWcx2xAENlIAClGDIdLNu/5tKMY='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

Whenever I try to load the index.php in the public site, if I look at the headers in the Inspector it says this for both the index.php file and the file.js:

```
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

I can't figure out where this is being set, or why the Headers in the .htaccess files aren't overriding this setting. I searched for this "Referrer Policy" in all the files in the apache folder and it didn't show up.

How can I get these errors to go away?

Comment: do not use Header unset and Header add, just use Header set or Header always set.. Also, paste the results of "curl" connecting to the url you are testing with parameters -I or -v so you can see the returned headers and can paste them here if necessary.